# Python taking data from sys.stdin.readline() with if statements

Tags: python

I am quite new to python. One of the problems I've been having is using sys.stdin.readline(). I've written the code out like this con = sys.stdin.readline(). After doing this I put a if statement to look at that new data. After doing this no matter what I type the output is the exact same. Here is the code that I am using:

```
import sys
print('Nice and quick what\'s your name?')
name = sys.stdin.readline()
print('What a great name!')
def moon_weight(weight, gain):
    for year in range(1,16):
        weight = weight + gain
        moon = weight * 0.165
        if year == 15:
            print()
            print('Year %s: Your weight on the moon is %s' % (year, moon))
            print()
            print('That\'s the end of this program for you, %s' % name)
            print('Have a nice day bye!')
        else:
            print()
            print('Year %s: Your weight on the moon is %s' % (year, moon))
            print()
            print('Press enter to see the next year...')
            print('If you would not like to see the next year type no')
            nex = sys.stdin.readline()
        if nex == 'no':
                print()
                print('Ok, ending program now.')
                print('Ending...')
                break
            
            
moon_weight(55,1)
```

When I run the code and type no, the code continues on like I didn't write anything.

Comment: I could suggest instead of using ```sys.stdin.readline()``` to get a name from the user, use ```input('What is your name')``` for example, the same goes for the ```nex``` variable.

Comment: @PrimeBeat thank you! After changing that it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use input instead.

```
import sys
print('Nice and quick what\'s your name?')
name = input()
print('What a great name!')
def moon_weight(weight, gain):
    for year in range(1,16):
        weight = weight + gain
        moon = weight * 0.165
        if year == 15:
            print()
            print('Year %s: Your weight on the moon is %s' % (year, moon))
            print()
            print('That\'s the end of this program for you, %s' % name)
            print('Have a nice day bye!')
        else:
            print()
            print('Year %s: Your weight on the moon is %s' % (year, moon))
            print()
            print('Press enter to see the next year...')
            print('If you would not like to see the next year type no')
            nex = input()

        if nex == 'no':
            print()
            print('Ok, ending program now.')
            print('Ending...')
            break
                    
moon_weight(55,1)
```

Answer (score 4):

`sys.stdin.readline()` returns the string `"no\n"`

Using the python interpreter interactively and testing `sys.stdin.readline() == 'no'` will return `False`.

You may try instead `if "no" in sys.stdin.readline():`

The problem is you are loooking for the EXACT string "no".
So even if using `input()` you may have problems if the user adds
spaces or types `"No"`,`"No!"`, `"NO"` etc.

So you would have to normalize your string first.

`if "no" in sys.stdin.readline().strip().lower():`

could be a first simple approximation.

BTW. you can use underscores like `next_` or `_next` if your variable
name clashes with keywords.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to above comments, consider refactoring your code to only have one place for actual calculations:

```
def moon_weight(weight, gain, name, year_limit=16):
    for year in range(1, year_limit):
        weight += gain
        moon = weight * 0.165
        # This is the actual calculation. No need to repeat it twice
        print('Year %s: Your weight on the moon is %s.' % (year, moon))
        answer = input('Press enter to see the next year or type "no" to stop:')
        # This is the only branching logic for the quick stop
        if answer == 'no':
            print('Ok, ending program now.')
            print('Ending...')
            break
    else: # Special construct for the loop that runs if there was no break.
        print('That\'s the end of this program for you, %s' % name)
        print('Have a nice day bye!')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = input("What's your name?\n")
    moon_weight(55, 1, name, 5)
```